# coffeescript loop that iterates over tags in list of tags

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I couldn't get this to work.

```
students = ["nova", "alexander", "johnathan", "amanda"]
classColors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "purple", "blue"]
h1Tags = [] # h1 tag generator
countTags = []
for color in classColors
  for room in rooms
    h1Tags.push("##{color}-#{room}-h1")
    countTags.push("##{color}-#{room}-count")


populateChildCount = ->
# work in progress
  for tag in h1Tags
    for count in countTags
      $(tag).text $(count).children().length
```

I want to change the text of `tag` with the amount of children the div id has.

Comment: what exactly is not working about this?

Comment: @maxpleaner the node text. BTW I found another, more efficient way to do what I wanted to do, but I would still like to know what went wrong. All the nodes are populated with '0'

Comment: I'm guessing `$(count)` was returning nothing, or maybe something with no children ... it's impossible to know without looking at the HTML. In the future you should try and include all required information in your question.